# ionic Build Error: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have updated android studio and updated my ionic project with the latest version of android sdk now when i try to build the app i am getting the following error and even the android folder structure is also changed.

> cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):/home/nidhin/Documents/Nidhinbackup/F/ionic_framework/Kanakupillai/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

Android version i have installed is 7.1.2